# How To Echo If Variable = something?

Tags: cmd

```
@echo off
set/p=password
if %password%=random echo password correct
```

How Do I Echo It?
I Keep Getting An Error

Comment: Windows 7... I need it to echo password correct when the input is random.

Comment: You mean when the input equals the word random?

Comment: As an aside, I don't recommend `set /p` to get password input because the input is displayed on the screen as you type.

Comment: `set /p password=Enter Password`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the syntay for `if` is:

```
if %variable%==content echo blabla
```

But you should write

```
if "%variable%"=="content" ....
```

to prevent a syntax error if the input is empty.